# How come if $\ i\ $ not of the following form, then $12i + 5$ must be prime?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I know if $\ i\ $  of the following form $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $ or $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1, \ \ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+},i \in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$,

then $\ 12i + 5\ $ must be composite number, because:

$12(3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1) + 5 = 36x^2 + (72y - 36)x + (12y - 7) = (6x + 12y - 7)(6x  + 1)$

How come if $\ i\ $ not of the following form $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $ and $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1\ $,

then $12i + 5$ must be prime? $\ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+},i \in \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}$.

For example: $\ 5 = \ 3*1^2 + (6*1-3)*1 - 1\ $ ,when $\ x = y = 1\ $, as proved before,$\ 5*12+5\ $ must be composite number;

$\ 0, \ 1. \ 2.\ 3.\ 4\ $ can't of the following form $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $ and $\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1\ $,

$\ 12*0 + 5 = 5\ $, $\ 5 $ is prime,$\ 12*1 + 5 = 17\ $, $\ 17 $ is prime, and so on, sure this is true and there's a long proof, but too long to see.

Comment: 1. What do you mean it's formed by? 2. Do you mean to ask if $12i+5$ is prime in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]$?

Comment: Does it say somewhere that this is true?

Comment: @Spock Obviously, $i$ is not here a complex number with square $-1$. It is just a variable name for an integer. As for "formed", I think the OP means "of the following form" with $x$ and $y$ some integers too. However, the post is not clear enough, and the OP should edit it in order to clarify things.

Comment: "there's a long proof, but too long to see" --- what does that mean? Does that mean you know a proof that $12i+5$ is prime, but you aren't going to tell us where to find it?