# How to prove sum of two numbers of the two following forms can be equals to sum of two numbers not of the forms?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

The two forms are:

$\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x - y\ $

$\ 3x^2 + (6y-3)x + y - 1, \ \ x,y \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$

For example:

$\ \  \ 5 = \ 3*1^2 + (6*1-3)*1 - 1\ $ ,when $\ x = y = 1\ $,of the two forms
 $\ 13 = \ 3*1^2 + (6*2-3)*1 + 2 - 1\ $ ,when $\ x = 1,y = 2\ $,of the two forms

$5+13=14+4$,$\ \ 14,4\ $ not of the two forms

Comment: Haven't you just proved it?  Are you asking why $21$ is not of one of the two forms?

Comment: It doesnt matter 21 is not of the two forms.I havent proved by myself.

Comment: Didn't we have a question about these forms just a couple of days ago?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775387/how-come-if-i-not-of-the-following-form-then-12i-5-must-be-prime also posted to MO.

Comment: Sorry for  $5+13=19+2$, I have edit that.This question looks like that question,but this is another question.

Comment: @mike If you are going to ask many questions on this site, you should register an account.